# Two-sided improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

What is one way to show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^4 e^{x/2}}{e^x+1}\, dx$$
converges? I see it is an even function so it is enough to show that it converges for $[0,1]$.  Moreover, it is nonnegative and decreasing after some point so I can use the integral test.  But then it reduces to showing that
$$\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^4 e^{x/2}}{e^x+1} < \infty,$$
but that is difficult.

Alternatively we can use integration by substitution.  Letting $u = e^x+1, du = e^x dx$, we have $[\log(u-1)]^4 = x^4$ and $u \to \pm \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.  Therefore we can rewrite the integral as
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^4 (e^x)^{1/2}}{e^x+1} \frac{e^x}{e^x}\, dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{[\log(u-1)]^4u^{1/2}}{u(u-1)}\, du \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{[\log(u-1)]^4}{u^{3/2} - u^{1/2}}\, du.
\end{align*}
How can I proceed from here?  I was thinking to use the $p$-series test but am unsure.  Thanks.  The other alternative is the ratio test but I think that would be inconclusive.

Comment: Formatting tip: a bunch of `\displaystyle` and `\dfrac` is often a hint you should be using a display instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the integral up into two: $x>0$ and $x<0$.  In the first case, the integrand is less than $x^4 e^{-x/2}$ which has a finite value

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, x^4 \, e^{-x/2} = 2^5 \cdot 4!$$

The the second case, sub $-x \leftarrow x$ and you get a similar bound.

Comment: I don't see how that substitution does anything for you.

Comment: @dfeuer: You end up getting $$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^4 \, e^{-x/2}}{1+e^{-x}}$$ which is bounded from above by the above factorial integral.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped. I think I need to get more familiar with the factorial integral.